# Can for-loop index depend on the varying length of a list?

Tags: python

I wrote some code in which the forloop index varies over a range depending on the length of a list, and the length of the list is changeable inside the loop. Here is a simplified code:

```
>>> ml = [1,2,3]
>>> for i in range(0, len(ml)):
...     if ml[i] == 2:
...         ml.pop(i)
...     i
... 
0
2
1
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in <module>
IndexError: list index out of range
```

I guess that `len(ml)` is evaluated once at the first iteration of the forloop, and not in the following iterations, so the index goes out of range.

But could it be possible to update the index range along the iterations? Thanks.

Comment: try using `for item in ml:` instead.

Comment: what are you actually trying to achieve?

Comment: It's easier if you just make a new list: `new = [n for n in ml if n != 2]`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`range(0, len(ml))` is evaluated once, and generates the list of values for `i`.

You can simply replace the for loop by a while loop:

```
i = 0
while i < len(ml):
  if ml[i] == 2:
    ml.pop(i)
    continue
  i+=1
```

Comment: Your answer is in essence the exact same as mine.

Comment: except for that note about range being evaluated once at the beginning (even if you imply it ... ):P which is really pretty important ... that said you both resolve his issue

Answer (score 4):

```
new_list = [x for x in my_list if x != 2]
```

is much better or

```
new_list = filter(lambda x:x!=2,my_list)
```

you should not really remove elements while iterating through a list unless you have a very very very good (so good I have never heard of it) reason

if you want the elements to replace the current list

```
my_list[:] = [x for x in my_list if x != 2]
```

or you can simply overwrite it and let pythons very good garbage collector delete the old one

```
my_list = [x for x in my_list if x != 2]
```

Comment: Ya this is way better

Comment: this creates a new list, which may not be desirable

Answer (score 1):

This behavior makes sense because you're actualy not iterating through the list, but rather the range:

```
ml = [1, 2, 3]

for i in range(0, len(ml)):
    print(i)
```

Give the following output:

```
0
1
2
```

Using `for item in ml:` instead actually iterates through the list:

```
ml = [1, 2, 3]
    for i in ml:
        if i == 2:
            ml.pop(i)
        print(i)
```

Result:

```
1
2
```

---

In response to comments here's a better idea of what's happening:

```
ml = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
for i in ml:
   if i == 2:
       ml.pop(1) # pop second element in list
   print(i)
```

gives the following output:

```
1
2
4
5
6
7
```

Using a while loop gives you the same result:

```
ml = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]

i = 0
while i < len(ml):
    print(ml[i])
    if ml[i] == 2:
        ml.pop(i)
    i+=1

1
2
4
5
6
7
```

This means that you can pop elements, however you cannot gaurentee that all the elements are correctly processed.

Comment: this only works because you remove the last element of the list, in the question the second element is removed. If the second element is removed in your case it raises an exception, it is not allowed to change size of list while iterating.

Comment: @mguijarr `it is not allowed to change the size of list while iterating` that's not exactly true.  My function above changed the size of the list and it worked fine.  You are correct however in pointing out that I'm not 'popping' the same elements.

Comment: I think you would if you just put the increment in an else ... (I gave you +1 cause this is also correct)